# Android Studio audio file frequency

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, frequency

I am working on a project and right now I am stuck.

I need to get the frequency from the audio track. So far I have looked into FFT and waveform visualization libraries but they have not really given me what I need or I have just understood them wrong.

I would put up a code but so far I have gotten nothing to work that would get the frequency from the audio in Android Studio. Could someone guide me in the right direction as to what library I am supposed to look for or what is the best way to get the frequency?

Comment: Are you planning on adding visualizers to it or just the frequency itself?

Comment: I dont need the common visualizer itself. I am trying to create a guitar hero like app and I need to get the frequency to visualize it like it is in guitar hero vocals. But I dont think it will be that hard once I get the frequency on exact given time. (not sure what the output will be if i "scan" the audio file for frequency)

Comment: Anyways I believe that once i get the frequency I will be able to figure out the rest but im not that good with the sound part and scanning audio which is why I would like help.